# Auto_increment stops script from creating table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My server is on hostgator running on a linux centOS.

I'm simply trying to create a table within my database and I figured out how to get the table to get created. Although when I add the AUTO_INCREMENT setting the code doesn't execute and the table isn't created.

Why would this be and how can I correct it?

Here is my code:

```
$members2_table = "CREATE TABLE ninja08_codin.members2(
        id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        first_name VARCHAR(40),
        last_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
        email VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
        date_joined TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        cred VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL)";
```

Comment: And what error does `mysql_error()` or the equivalent for whatever MySQL API you're using tell you?

Comment: Also, you did `DROP TABLE` before attempting to recreate it after you created it w/o AUTO_INCREMENT, right?

Comment: yea I dropped the table that would get created if the script worked. I didn't get any errors. It simply wouldn't create the table when I refreshed the list of tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `AUTO_INCREMENT` you may have to assign the column as a primary key:

```
$members2_table = "CREATE TABLE ninja08_codin.members2(
        id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        first_name VARCHAR(40),
        last_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
        email VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
        date_joined TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        cred VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id))";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query will give error

`there can be only one auto column and it must be defines as a key, so add primary key to id field`

```
    $members2_table = "CREATE TABLE ninja08_codin.members2(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(40),
    last_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    date_joined TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    cred VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL)";
```